# Placing annotations on Implementation class methods and using proxy with reflection

Tags: java, reflection, proxy, annotations

I am working with proxy-reflection-annotations concept in java. I have created a proxy with Proxy.getInstance method.What I observed is this method takes only interface as parameters. So while using annotations, I can only place annotations on method names in Interface, but I would like to place annotations on methods in implementations of those interfaces.

So how can I achieve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have understood that JDKProxy is used when proxying interface via implementation and CBLIB proxy is used via inheritance(subclass extends superclass) proxying.